# how to get to_epoch(sysdate-90) in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, unix-timestamp, sysdate

I have a query which runs good in Oracle, but i want to use the same query in Hive.

query:

```
select count(mem_id)  
from mem 
where cobrand_id = '10001372' 
and user_type_id =1  
and status_ind <>3 
and LAST_ACCESSED >= to_epoch(sysdate-90);
```

Also, I have LAST_ACCESSED coulmn in double.example value of LAST_ACCEESSED is : `1.554386487E9`, not sure what value this is i am guessing this could be seconds.

tried:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP( string date, string pattern )
FROM_UNIXTIME( bigint number_of_seconds  [, string format] )
```

No luck. Can someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems 1.554386487E9 is the same unix epoch time stored in double, displayed in engineering notation, and it can be casted to BIGINT.

Checking your example:

```
select from_unixtime(cast(1.554386487E9 as bigint));
OK
2019-04-04 07:01:27
```

Does this timestamp look good?

If yes, then use  `unix_timestamp(concat(date_sub(current_date,90),' 00:00:00'))` to get epoch time for current date - 90 days.

Your query fixed:

```
select count(mem_id)  
from mem 
where cobrand_id = '10001372' 
and user_type_id =1  
and status_ind <>3 
and cast(LAST_ACCESSED as BIGINT) >=  unix_timestamp(concat(date_sub(current_date,90),' 00:00:00'))
```

Comment: Thanks @leftjoin for your answer.  i have tried the below.

from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-90*60*60*24, 'yyyyMMdd'); but i got the same results for 90 and 180 days and even without any days.  I have replaced my query with your answer thanks again.